# Why does flake8 throw a SyntaxError when calling print in a lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, flake8

I use the vim-flake8 (v0.5) plugin with vim. With the following code:

```
fn = lambda: print("Hey")
```

I surprisingly get the error message:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax [E901]

But nonetheless the python interpreter doesn't throw any error... Why does flake8 tell this?

Comment: Is vim-flake8 using Python2 with Flake8 or Python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fn = lambda: print("Hey")
```

is invalid in Python 2.7 but it's valid in Python 3.4. As such you may be checking the code against a different Python version from the one you're actually using to run the code.

Comment: Indeed, flake8 uses CPython 2.7.8, but how to change its python version ?

Comment: @Spirine: run `which flake8` to check which flake8 executable you're using and make sure it matches the Python version you're using. So if you have a virtual environment you need to install flake8 inside that virtual environment to match the Python version in that virtual environment. Otherwise, update flake8 globally to match the Python version that is installed globally.